# Переименование нового файла на имя старого и удаление старого файла

Tags: java

У меня есть 2 файла. Нужно переименовать новый файл на имя старого и удалить старый файл.

Пробовал делать так:

```
boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

Не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Естественно не получится! И Java тут не причем. Вы пытаетесь задать 2 файла с одинаковым именем в одной папке, операционная система вам этого не позволит.

Нужно скопировать имя старого файла, удалить его и уже тогда переименовывать новый.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось таким образом (нужно еще добавить проверку на ошибки):

```
inputFile.delete();
boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```